# How to resolve dependencies for installing mysql on ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm going to install mysql on ubuntu :

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

But there's a problem, and I don't know How to resolve it

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.1-mysql : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1ubuntu3.3) but 8.1.13-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a dependency issue with the package `php8.1-mysql` because it recquire `php8.1-common`

to solve this first update your package list `sudo apt-get update` then upgrade to the latest version `sudo apt-get upgrade` then try to install again `sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql`